# Include multiple salt states in specific order

Tags: salt-stack

I want to compose multiple existing salt states into a new one, where they need to be executed in a specific order.

The SaltStack [documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/include.html) explains that salt states can be included.
As I understand, the included states will be run before the rest of the sls file.
Example:

```
include:
  - config-pulled
  - service-restarted
```

Using this example, I want `service-restarted` to be executed after `config-pulled` and only if `config-pulled` was successful.

But the execution order of multiple included states is not guaranteed. The docs say:
`... If you need to guarantee order of execution, consider using requisites.`

I could imagine to use requisities directly on the include. For example:

```
include:
  - config-pulled
  - service-restarted:
      require:
        - config-pulled
```

But this does not work.

**Questions**

- How to use requisites when including states?
- Do I have to use an [orchestrate script](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/orchestrate/orchestrate_runner.html) instead?

Comment: This seems related, but I don't understand what is the solution: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/11893

Comment: Is there maybe a way to import a state without executing it? Then one could make all states available and define their execution order by using `require`

Comment: Mmmh, on a second thought, I do not want to make assumptions about the names of states in the sls file. The sls files should be seen as "black box". Thus, using require to order imported states from the sls file is not optimal because one has to make assumptions about the ids used in the sls files.

Comment: I am using an orchestrate script now. I did not find another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use orch and you can use `onchanges` requisites with a `test.succeed_with_changes`.

tested on salt **3004.2**

To sum up the demo, `onchanges` inhibits the execution of the `test.succeed_with_changes` by default unless there is a change in the given state (`tests.config-pulled`). `onchanges_in` does the same the other way around and inhibits server reload unless `test.succeed_with_changes` is modified (in the salt sense).

Example:

```
/srv/salt
├── tests
│   ├── config-pulled.sls
│   ├── init.sls
│   └── service-restarted.sls
```

`config-pulled.sls`

```
 config-pulled:
   file.managed:
     - name: /tmp/config
     - contents: 1000
 # uncomment random to simulate a change (or change 1000 just over)
 #    - contents: {{ range(1000, 9999) | random }}
```

`service-restarted.sls`

```
 service-restarted:
   cmd.run:
     - name: echo service-restarted
```

`init.sls`

```
 include:
   - tests.config-pulled
   - tests.service-restarted
 
 demo:
   test.succeed_with_changes:
     - onchanges:
       - sls: tests.config-pulled
     - onchanges_in:
       - sls: tests.service-restarted
```

This approach might become a bit difficult to maintain.

A completely different approach would be a reorganization of sls.
I usually separate server install and reload from customization (two separate sls), therefore when I have to handle configs, I include the "install and reload" one (usually `init.sls`) on top of any/all the sls managing the conf to import the states and configure my config states with `require_in`, ex:

```
myconf:
  file.managed:
    - [...]
    - require_in:
      - cmd: rndc-reload
```

or

```
myconf:
  file.managed:
    - [...]
     - require_in:
      - service: haproxy
```

Note: this approach scale well as several states or even sls can manage configs using this mechanism and the daemon will be reloaded only once after all configs are set.

### UPDATE

Add output to show specific order

**Without changes**

```
# salt-call state.apply tests 
local:
----------
          ID: config-pulled
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /tmp/config
      Result: True
     Comment: File /tmp/config is in the correct state
     Started: 14:49:20.363480
    Duration: 15.688 ms
     Changes:   
----------
          ID: demo
    Function: test.succeed_with_changes
      Result: True
     Comment: State was not run because none of the onchanges reqs changed
     Started: 14:49:20.380447
    Duration: 0.004 ms
     Changes:   
----------
          ID: service-restarted
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: echo service-restarted
      Result: True
     Comment: State was not run because none of the onchanges reqs changed
     Started: 14:49:20.380536
    Duration: 0.002 ms
     Changes:   

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 3
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     3
Total run time:  15.694 ms
```

**With changes**

```
# salt-call state.apply tests 
local:
----------
          ID: config-pulled
    Function: file.managed
        Name: /tmp/config
      Result: True
     Comment: File /tmp/config updated
     Started: 14:49:15.757487
    Duration: 18.292 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
                  --- 
                  +++ 
                  @@ -1 +1 @@
                  -1001
                  +1002
----------
          ID: demo
    Function: test.succeed_with_changes
      Result: True
     Comment: Success!
     Started: 14:49:15.777084
    Duration: 0.549 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              testing:
                  ----------
                  new:
                      Something pretended to change
                  old:
                      Unchanged
----------
          ID: service-restarted
    Function: cmd.run
        Name: echo service-restarted
      Result: True
     Comment: Command "echo service-restarted" run
     Started: 14:49:15.777785
    Duration: 7.69 ms
     Changes:   
              ----------
              pid:
                  4130033
              retcode:
                  0
              stderr:
              stdout:
                  service-restarted

Summary for local
------------
Succeeded: 3 (changed=3)
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     3
Total run time:  26.531 ms
```

Comment: In `init.sls` there are includes for both states. I think these will be run as part of the include. And then again as part of `demo` state? So will they run twice, first in no specific order, then in order defined via `onchanges` and `onchanges_in`?

Comment: no it's not the case, include works a bit like in a template way. The way salt works is it create the overall list of state to execute (with takes in consideration includes, top.sls etc depending on how you call it) then orders them (to make the order idempotent). If you want to ensure all the state of an imported SLS is run before, you have to mention it.
Feel free to give a test to states I just gave and for a matter of test I also tried to invert onchanges and onchanges_in and it works as expected (or a good amount of luck).

Comment: I've updated my answer with relevant output of both runs (with and without changes). You'll notice that the `init.sls` state is executed between the two others. You can test by switching the `onchanges` and `onchanges_in`, execution order will be swapped, keeping `demo` in the middle

Answer (score 0):

includes are not states. so requisites will not work with them.

as for the ticket you pointed to that became https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.test.html#salt.states.test.nop test.nop which is just a state that doesn't do anything.

for handling what you are talking about you would do something like

```
include:
  - http
  - libvirt

run_http:
  test.nop:
    - require:
      - sls: http

run_libvirt:
  test.nop:
    - require:
      - test: run_http
      - sls: libvirt
```

Comment: `includes are not states`. This may be true from a syntactical point of view. But conceptually I argue that executing multiple states results in a new state, namely their composition. Thereby, the execution order may be relevant. SaltStack's lack to create such a composition is a severe lack IMO. Note that an orchestrate script (although a solution to my problem at hand) is not itself a salt state and thus does not implement this kind of composition (because it can not be included/composed the same way).

Comment: `Thereby, the execution order may be relevant`. Example: `config-pulled.sls` pulls from a git repo. It is a valid salt state (idempotent etc.). `service-restarted.sls` restarts a service. Again, it is a valid salt state. Now I want to compose `config-pulled-then-service-restarted.sls`. If the service is restarted before the config is pulled, then the service might miss changed configuration. Thus, the order of execution in the composition is relevant. EDIT: I changed the original question and your answer to use this real-word example.

Comment: Your answer does not work. In my test, the test.nop parts are executed in required order. But the includes are not (at least in the output printed by salt). And indeed this would be valid, because there is still no statement that `config-pulled` must be executed before `service-restarted`. Thus, the following orders are possible: (config-pulled, service-restarted, run_config_pulled, run_service_restarted), (service-restarted, config-pulled, run_config_pulled, run_service_restarted), (config-pulled, run_config_pulled, service-restarted, run_service_restarted)

Comment: @mihca Salt does not lack such a composition. That's exactly what the `sls` is. An orchestration can be used to explicitly order these compositions, or you can do it as in this example via transitive orderings on `nop` states.

Comment: @whytewolf your example does appear to be incorrect though, as when a state has multiple requisites there is no defined order they must be run, other than "both before this one".

Comment: @mihca they don't have to be `nop` states either, but in the absence of any existing states to use they are available.